# MultiOutputClassifier with text data in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to make MultiOutputClassifier in Python with scikit learn lib. I want to get the features and accuracy of the model.
All data that I have in my database are categorical (string values).
IDK why, but I always get this error:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '<=50K'`

I the error is in this line:
`model = cls.fit(features_train, result_train)`

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier    

df = pd.read_csv('income_education.csv')

#creating features and results for my model
features = df.iloc[:,-1]
results = df.iloc[:,:-1]    

#spliting my data into train and test
features_train, features_test, result_train, result_test = train_test_split(features, results, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

classifier = MultiOutputClassifier(tree.DecisionTreeClassifier())

#model fitting
cls = classifier
model = cls.fit(features_train, result_train)

pred = model.predict([cv.transform(['more'])])
print(pred)

# How to check accuracy of this classifier
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simply because the classifier is expecting float values, but you are providing it string. You need to encode the string to float values using [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) for labels and encode features using [OneHotEncoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), [OrdinalEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder), etc.

Here checkout these links for more information about encoding categorical(string) values using sklearn

- [Label Encoder vs One Hot Encoding](https://medium.com/@contactsunny/label-encoder-vs-one-hot-encoder-in-machine-learning-3fc273365621)
- [Encoding Categorical Features](https://towardsdatascience.com/encoding-categorical-features-21a2651a065c)
- [Tutorial on handling categorical data in Python](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/categorical-data)

**Update**
Read this official documentation from Scikit-learn to encode categorical values [at this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features).

Comment: Ok, but should I take float values for features or results (I think features)?
Also, can you give me an example code?

Comment: You need to convert them both to float.

Comment: I do not get how can my features be floats?
I mean, for example, if i have some values and result, result is categorical values ("yes","maybe","no"), I want to predict my features, why should I convert my result to float?

Also, im reading documentation that you sent me,  but i cant find a way to do this with my dataset

Comment: @taga, that is exactly what encoding categorical values mean. "Yes" is encoded to say 1, "maybe" is 2 and "no" is encoded to 3. Accordingly all your categorical features need to be encoded as well. This is because, the classifier can only work on float values, not strings. If you check the documentation, all the classifier need float values.

Answer (score 1):

First problem in your code is that you need to encode the categorical columns and also onehotencoding is necessary . Second Problem is that you need to replace the two variables i.e. features and results